# How to calculate result archive size created as Azure shared file by adding json to input archive?

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, zip, filesize

I got a zip archive as input file. I extract it to azure shared folder, then add a json file to extracted directory. After that, I need to make a new archive from this directory (with all data from input archive include json file). How to calculate result archive size or how to rescale result archive size to remove empty space without real data?
Right now I calculate maxSize as input archive size * 1.5 plus json length, because I don't know compression of input archive, so I can't just use input archive size plus json length.
Also, I can not just sum up file size from all files in extracted directory, because small files (e.g. simple txt file with just one symbol inside) will create archive with bigger size than sum of input files. After extracting of new archive created this way, I also got an error message about the disparity between the size of the archive and the payload block.

I have tryed some different approaches, e.g. create result file with 0 size, calculate size while compressing data and set it to result file by SetHttpHeaders, but anyway I do wrong size calculation. Please, help me.

Here is code example for new archive creation.

```
  private async Task<ShareFileClient> CreateNewArchive(ShareDirectoryClient rootDirectory, string fileName, ShareDirectoryClient extractDirectory, long maxSize)
        {
            var resultFile = rootDirectory.GetFileClient(fileName);
            //TODO: maxSize - calculate and/or resize somehow (how?)
            var options = new ShareFileOpenWriteOptions { MaxSize = maxSize };
            using (var zipArchive = new ZipArchive(await resultFile.OpenWriteAsync(true, 0, options), ZipArchiveMode.Create))
            {
                foreach (var item in extractDirectory.GetFilesAndDirectories())
                    await CreateFromAny(zipArchive, item, extractDirectory, string.Empty);
            }
            
            return resultFile;
        }

        private async Task CreateFromAny(ZipArchive archive, ShareFileItem entry, ShareDirectoryClient sourceDir, string currentPath)
        {
            if (entry.IsDirectory)
            {
                await CreateFromDirectory(archive, sourceDir.GetSubdirectoryClient(entry.Name), currentPath);
            }
            else
            {
                var path = Path.Combine(currentPath, entry.Name);
                var extractedFile = sourceDir.GetFileClient(entry.Name);
                await using (var fileZip = archive.CreateEntry(path).Open())
                {
                    await using (var entryStream = await extractedFile.OpenReadAsync())
                    {
                        await entryStream.CopyToAsync(fileZip);
                        await entryStream.FlushAsync();
                    }

                    await fileZip.FlushAsync();
                }
            }
        }

        private async Task CreateFromDirectory(ZipArchive archive, ShareDirectoryClient sourceDir, string currentPath)
        {
            currentPath = Path.Combine(currentPath, sourceDir.Name);
            
            archive.CreateEntry($"{currentPath}/");
            foreach (var file in sourceDir.GetFilesAndDirectories())
                await CreateFromAny(archive, file, sourceDir, currentPath);
        }
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

- Using file archive, I am able to calculate the length of the ZIP file and JSON file from the Azure Blob Storage.

```cs
long newArchiveSize = inputArchiveSize + jsonFileSize;
```

```cs
string conn_String = "connection_String";  
string container = "container";  
string blob = "blob"; 
BlobServiceClient bServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(conn_String); 
BlobContainerClient containerClient = bServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(container); 
BlobClient b_Client = containerClient.GetBlobClient(blob);
BlobProperties properties = b_Client.GetProperties();
long size = properties.ContentLength; 
var ar_Size = new { ArSize = size };  
string jString = JSerializer.Serialize(ar_Size);
Console.WriteLine($"Blob size: {size} bytes");  
Console.WriteLine($"J: {jString}");
Console.ReadLine();
```

- After running the above code,  got the output as below.

[image]

```cs
BlobClient jsonBlobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(jsonBlobName);  
BlobProperties jsonProperties = jsonBlobClient.GetProperties();  
long jsonFileSize = jsonProperties.ContentLength;
```

Output:

[image]